# python xml and csv extract

Tags: python, xml, pandas, csv

i have 2 set of files - (1) CSV file (the main file) (2) XML file.

CSV file -

```
emp_id
1
2
3
4
```

XML File -

```
<employee>
    <emp id="1" />
    <emp id="2" active="yes">
        <tag k="age" v="55" />
    </emp>
    <emp id="3" active="yes">
        <tag k="name" v="scott" />
    </emp>
    <emp id="4" active="no">
        <tag k="address" v="Texas" />
    </emp>
    <emp id="5" gender="male"/>
    <emp id="8" />
    <emp id="9" />
    <emp id="10" />
    <emp id="11" />
</employee>
```

My objective is have a csv file where the emp_id from the csv file is matched with the XML file, and only the matched emp_id is created in the new csv file. I need 2 csv files like below -

1st file.

```
emp_id,active,gender
1,,
2,yes,
3,yes,
4,no,
5,,male
```

2nd file.

```
emp_id,key,value
2,age,55
3,name,scott
4,address,Texas
```

I can read the CSV file in pandas, and XML file in Python. But don't know how to combine them and extract keys and value from the XML

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your current code? Please share it and explain what is the problem

Comment: The current code consists of reading the csv file and xml file only. I am struck in the logic of combining a csv file data with the xml file and extracting the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets create first dataframe:

```
# this dataframe should be read from csv in your case
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'emp_id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})
```

Than define XML:

```
xml = '''<employee>
    <emp id="1" />
    <emp id="2" active="yes">
        <tag k="age" v="55" />
    </emp>
    <emp id="3" active="yes">
        <tag k="name" v="scott" />
    </emp>
    <emp id="4" active="no">
        <tag k="address" v="Texas" />
    </emp>
    <emp id="5" gender="male"/>
    <emp id="8" />
    <emp id="9" />
    <emp id="10" />
    <emp id="11" />
</employee>'''
```

Read data from XML:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
# here we read XML from string, in your case it should be read from file
root = et.fromstring(xml)
emps = root.xpath('//employee/emp')
# iterate over elements "emp" and extract data
for emp in emps:
  # here we extract attributes id, active and gender
  d['id'].append(int(emp.get('id')))
  d['active'].append(None if emp.get('active') is None else emp.get('active'))
  d['gender'].append(None if emp.get('gender') is None else emp.get('gender'))
  # here we extract age
  age = emp.find('./tag[@k="age"]')
  d['age'].append(None if age is None else age.get('v'))
  # here we extract address
  address = emp.find('./tag[@k="address"]')
  d['address'].append(None if address is None else address.get('v'))
```

Than create dataframe from dict:

```
df_xml = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Than merge data using emp_id / id columns:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df, df_xml, left_on = 'emp_id', right_on='id', how = 'inner')
del df_merged['id']

df_merged.head(10)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: thanks. but there are multiple key values. I have shown just a sample. I dont want the output to have many columns.

Comment: In that case you can leave in the loop `for emp in emps:` only first line: `d['id'].append(int(emp.get('id')))`. That will create a dataframe with only one column.

Answer (score 2):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils
empIds = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
# empIds = [id.strip() for id in utils.getFileLines('your csv file path')[1:]]

xml = '''<employee>
    <emp id="1" />
    <emp id="2" active="yes">
        <tag k="age" v="55" />
    </emp>
    <emp id="3" active="yes">
        <tag k="name" v="scott" />
    </emp>
    <emp id="4" active="no">
        <tag k="address" v="Texas" />
    </emp>
    <emp id="5" gender="male"/>
    <emp id="8" />
    <emp id="9" />
    <emp id="10" />
    <emp id="11" />
</employee>
'''
# xml = utils.getFileContent('your xml file path')

rows1 = [['emp_id', 'active', 'gender']]
rows2 = [['emp_id', 'key', 'value']]
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
for id in empIds:
    emp = doc.select('emp#' + id)
    if emp:
        rows1.append([id, emp.get('active'), emp.get('gender')])
        tags = emp.selects('tag')
        if tags:
            for tag in tags:
                rows2.append([id, tag['k'], tag['v']])

utils.save2csv('csv1.csv', rows1, newline='')
utils.save2csv('csv2.csv', rows2, newline='')
```

Result csv1:

```
emp_id,active,gender
1,,
2,yes,
3,yes,
4,no,
5,,male
```

Result csv2:

```
emp_id,key,value
2,age,55
3,name,scott
4,address,Texas
```

Answer (score 1):

**First df:** Read XML and create DataFrame

```
import xmltodict
with open('XmlFile.xml') as fd:
    xmlfile = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
df_xmlfile = pd.DataFrame(xmlfile["employee"]["emp"])
df_xmlfile.columns = [col.replace("@","") for col in df_xmlfile.columns]
```

Read CSV as DataFrame

```
df_csvfile = csvfile=pd.read_csv("CsvFile.txt")
```

Join boths dfs

```
df_first = df_csvfile.join(df_xmlfile[["active", "gender"]])
```

**Second df:**
Get rows containing a tag, unpack those rows to get the keys and values and create second df

```
df_temp = df_xmlfile[~df_xmlfile["tag"].isna()][["id", "tag"]]
df_second = pd.DataFrame({"emp_id": df_temp["id"],
              "key": [row["@k"] for row in df_temp["tag"]],
              "value": [row["@v"] for row in df_temp["tag"]]})
```